# Problem with intro.js when navigating in single page app

Tags: intro.js

I'm setting up a number of hints for a page in my single page app with React.
It's a data driven page which renders an image, which depends on what has been clicked on the previous page.
All works fine at first. Image1 is displayed and all hints are displayed at the correct position. When going back to the previous page, selecting a different Image2 (different size) and then going back to the page with the hints, then Image2 is shown but all hints are shifted in position. The shift depends on the size difference between the two images.
The DIVs which I'm using to set the hint configuration in JS are at the correct positions. Only the animated hints are off-position. It seems that intro.js is somehow remembering the inital hint positions, and ignoring the shifted, real DIV-positions when coming back to the page with a different image size.

I tried everything to "reset" the internal intro.js object (delete it, reset hints options, introJs().refresh(), ...), but nothing showed effect.

Does someone know a way to really re-initialize intro.js programmatically?

Thanks